# ld: warning: ignoring file libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /libsqlite3.dylib (2 slices)

Tags: ios, xcode

Has any one encountered this problem?
Can anyone provide an answer?

Despite the response to my first question I will give this another try:

Code supplied by the book "Beginning iOS 6 Development" (not my code ) generates the following error messages in the Xcode IDE

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusernamehere/Desktop/Xcode4/SQLitePersistence/libsqlite3.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/myusernamehere/Desktop/Xcode4/SQLitePersistence/libsqlite3.dylib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[ViewController applicationWillResignActive:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[ViewController applicationWillResignActive:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
      -[ViewController applicationWillResignActive:] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
```

and so on

This is downloaded code from the book NOT my code.
I have used the terminal to verify that sqlite3 is on my machine

```
Last login: Thu Mar 21 10:19:39 on ttys000
iMac1024:~ myusernamehere$ which sqlite3
/usr/bin/sqlite3
```

Once again 
Has any one encountered this problem?
Can you provide a solution here?

I'm not looking for remarks about how I'm not submitting this incorrectly or off topic or any other unhelpful remarks from anybody who was still nursing when I first started writing software professionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten to link the SQLite library. Add this in your project's "Build Phases," go to "Link with Libraries" and add `libsqite3`.

Comment: I was unaware of this process - Thank you very much!